# Header declaration for multi-dimensional array of unknown size in auto-generated cpp file?

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, header-files

As part of a project I'm working on, I've got a tool written in python that reads a CSV data file and generates a c++ file containing a statically declared 3 dimensional array. What the dimensions of the array are depend on the data in the CSV file and can change from compile to compile.

The declaration/definition looks like this:

```
const double aero_coeffs[81][25][8] = { ...
```

I've written a header to accompany the generated cpp file, and I'd really prefer not to have to generate that as well. However I get an error if I try to do this:

```
extern const double*** aero_coeffs;
```

or this (which I think is actually just the equivalent):

```
extern const double aero_coeffs[][][];
```

Any thoughts on the best way to go about this?

Comment: How do you want to use it ? An accessor function `get_aero_coeff(int i, int j, int k)` may be a solution.

Comment: `double [81][25][8]` may be compatible with `double*`, not with `double***`.

Answer (score 4):

You could perhaps use std::vector instead. With the new c++11 initalizer lists syntax, your generated file can be very similar. Something like:

```
std::vector< std::vector< std::vector< double > > > coeffs = {
    { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} },
    { {7, 8, 9}, {0, 0, 0} } };
```

Then, in the header, you just use:

```
extern std::vector< std::vector< std::vector< double > > > coeffs;
```

Comment: How is the performance of std::vector compared to normal arrays? IIRC vectors use arrays in the backend so access *should* be fast (and that's all I'm doing, the vector is const). However the 20 seconds it's added to the compile time of my project is a little disconcerting.

Comment: I don't recommend nested vector<> because each one witll produce an indirection to the child vector. Used nested std::array. It's as fast as regular static multidimensional arrays.

Comment: `std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 3> x{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 };`

Comment: @doug: `std::array` requires the size to be visible. what OP wants to avoid.

Comment: @Jarod42: vector<> suffers the same "problem." There is no way to create a compile time MDim data array without putting the dimensions somewhere, either explicitly or implicitly and the latter is more complex to implement.